# cl.exe build and debug is only usable when VS Code is run from the Developer Command Prompt for VS

Tags: c++, c, cl.exe

[Error with vscode-cpptools: "cl.exe build and debug is only usable when VS Code is run from the Developer Command Prompt for VS."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73347313/error-with-vscode-cpptools-cl-exe-build-and-debug-is-only-usable-when-vs-code)

I have the same problem with this.

When I try to complie, I see the small pop-up message :

cl.exe build and debug is only usable when VS Code is run from the Developer Command Prompt for VS.

[https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc#:~:text=To%20open%20the%20Developer%20Command,item%20to%20open%20the%20prompt.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc#:%7E:text=To%20open%20the%20Developer%20Command,item%20to%20open%20the%20prompt.)

With this link, I tried to figure it.

When I typed cl, it shows as it is in the documentation which is correct.

However, I still see the pop-up message above.

I changed the tasks.json as the documentation :

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "windows": {
      "options": {
        "shell": {
          "executable": "cmd.exe",
          "args": [
            "/C",
            // The path to VsDevCmd.bat depends on the version of Visual Studio you have installed.
            "\"C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/Tools/VsDevCmd.bat\"",
            "&&"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "tasks": [
      {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "cl.exe build active file",
        "command": "cl.exe",
        "args": [
          "/Zi",
          "/EHsc",
          "/Fe:",
          "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
          "${file}"
        ],
        "problemMatcher": [
          "$msCompile"
        ],
        "group": {
          "kind": "build",
          "isDefault": true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

But I still see the same message.

Is there any solutions with this?

(environment variable is also set)

Comment: I re-changed the tasks.json file as the default.  And it works.  I didn't need to change the tasks.json file.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by that comment? what is "the default"? how is that you simultaneously "re-changed it" causing it to work, and also "didn't need to change" it?

Answer (score 1):

I have already explained the solution to your problem in this question:
[setting up MSVC in Visual Studio code [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77546730/setting-up-msvc-in-visual-studio-code/77549755#77549755)
In short, the problem is that **your compiler needs to be in your path** when launching VS Code.
One posssible way to solve the problem is to open the *Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022* and typing in `>code .` to open VS Code with the path already set up.

Comment: if you think another question's answers answer this question, that's a good hint that duplicate closure might be in order instead of answering. please read the last section of [answer]