# put of __declspec not declare in the scoop in VScode C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, windows-10

I'm beginner in c++, I'm trying to run this simple code using __declspec inside a class for get & put properties but the VScode does not recognize the get&put properties within __declspec as shown in the picture[enter image description here] :https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqxzi.jpg

the full message of the error(above in the picture)

// This is the source code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class clsPerson
{
private:
    string _FirstName;

public:
    void SetFirstName(string FirstName)
    {
        _FirstName = FirstName;
    }
    string GetFirstName()
    {
        return _FirstName;
    }

    __declspec(property(get = GetFirstName, put = SetFirstName)) string FirstName;
};

int main()

{
    system("cls");
    clsPerson Person1;
    Person1.SetFirstName("Zak");
    cout << Person1.GetFirstName() << endl;
    // instead of the above we only write this
    Person1.FirstName = "Zak";
    cout << Person1.FirstName;

    system("pause>0");
    return 0;
};
```

I tried to include all possible libraries but with no result..

Thanks in advance for all help and support :-)

Comment: Seeing as you are a beginner, why did you decide on using VS Code, one of the more difficult-to-use IDEs?

Comment: Also note the syntax you're struggling with is not Standard C++ syntax. The compiler you're using underneath VS Code may not have the slightest clue what it means

Comment: Smurf, I'm dumb sometimes. Since that's what you're asking about, I'll wager that's exactly what the problem is. I recommend that you replace the image with the actual error messages as text so people who cannot or will not look at the image can participate in the question.

Comment: At this point I'm going out on a limb and saying it looks like you have the tools configured correctly, and the problem is you're using the wrong tools for the code you are trying to compile. I'm not sure if that needs a Borland compiler or a Microsoft compiler, or clang, or what, but what ever compiler that use of `__declspec` is for, you are not using it.

Comment: Side note: An identifier that starts with two underscores (and less commonly anything that has two underscores in a row anywhere in the name) is a non-standard implementation detail (or [someone screwed up with their naming](https://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/4581301)) Any time you see `__` in code you need to stop and make certain its for your tools and not some other tools.

Comment: Side-side note: If you read [that link about naming rules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/4581301) you'll notice `_FirstName` also breaks the the rules.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/property-cpp?view=msvc-170. looks like you need to define a c_cpp_configuration for using MSVC. see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc

Comment: If you are a beginner in C++ you should not touch `__declspec` with a six foot pole.

Comment: Thanks everybody for sharing, my VScode works fine I build I lot of algorithms problems with it, I think I need to include some kind of libraries in the header ???

Comment: This syntax is some non-standard stuff from MSVC (the compiler from Visual Studio). Other compilers might not support it. Just don't use it.

Comment: HolyBlackCat - what did you mean when you say stuff from MSVC ??

Comment: There are different compilers. MSVC is one of them, GCC is another. Eachs adds some unique features to C++ that only work on that compiler. The `__declspec(property` thing only seems to work on MSVC, while you're using GCC.

Comment: I had update my message above, I added the full picture of  error in run time

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - can fix this problem with compilers, I use to work with VScode(windows10) all of the time and I had take all my courses in c++ with it :-(, can I fix it without change into another IDE ???? plz help and thanks alot for your support

Comment: Just don't use this feature. Try to write standard C++, i.e. only use the things that all compilers support.

Comment: @starball - Yes I will try this official steps seems to be the logic solution, Thank you !

Comment: finaly it work guys with VScode, thanks *starball for the link :-), and @HolyBlackCat you have right my friend about the compiler MSVC it's only work with it, and for how .. I use one of buildtools made by Microsoft with VS and before lunch VScode you should executed with Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022, wich run&debug inside of VScode code with cl.exe (compiler) instead of gcc! It's a headache for me but I never give up. I wish they can let me share some picture here!!

Comment: @starball thanks a lot for the link and all who have support my question :-)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541. please also read [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Finally it work guys with VScode, thanks @starball for the link :-),thanks @HolyBlackCat you have right my friend about the compiler MSVC it's only work with it, and for how .. I use one of buildtools made by Microsoft with VS and before lunch VScode you should executed with Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022, wich run&debug inside of VScode code with cl.exe (compiler) instead of gcc! It's a headache for me but I never give up.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooC6g.jpg)

Comment: related: [Error with vscode-cpptools: "cl.exe build and debug is only usable when VS Code is run from the Developer Command Prompt for VS."](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73347313/11107541)

Comment: @starball exactly 100% true, but I noticed that if I try to debug&run with (cpp.exe or g++.exe) when I run from  (Developer Command Prompt for VS) it gives me : " Build finished with error(s)." ?!!

Comment: have you still not understood what several people have told you? your code uses MSVC-specific extensions to the C++ language. Why would you expect it to work for a compiler other than MSVC?

Comment: @starball I didn't mean the exact feature (__declspec(...) property) that we have already discuss and agree that it works only with MSVC ! What I meant in the last comment for the other simple codes(not include __declspec(...)).