# Run VScode from Dev Console through Context Menu

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, debugging, vscode-debugger

When trying to compile C programs with VS Code, the editor says it should be launched from Developer Console. However, that makes the `Open Vscode Here` from context menu pretty much useless.

How can I use the context menu option but also make it such that vscode is launched from Developer Console?

Upon checking Developer Console shortcut from start menu programs folder, the following command can be seen:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noe -c "&{Import-Module """C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\Tools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell.dll"""; Enter-VsDevShell e7f25a52}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll need to modify the context menu command so that it matches the Developer Console shortcut.

**Step 1:**
Navigate to the registry entry for the context menu. You might want to do this for all three (directory background, folder, file) context menu entries.

- `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\VSCode\command`
- `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\VSCode\command`
- `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\VSCode\command`

**Step 2:**
Double click on the `(Default)` key, and replace the value by:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -c "&{Import-Module """C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\Tools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell.dll"""; Enter-VsDevShell e7f25a52}; cd '%V'; code ."
```

**Explanation:**
The command in the shortcut loads the powershell with the debugger DLL which is required when working with C and VScode. This DLL needs to be loaded along with putting the path of the opened directory so VScode opens in that directory.
The first part is just the load DLL command and the second part uses `cd` command to change to directory specified by `%V` variable. And the vscode is then opened in current directory with `code .` command.