# Can't get VSCode to work with c++ 2020 standard using MSVC

Tags: visual-studio-code, c++20

While I could get cl to compile the exact same file I was feeding VSCode, using the flag to force 2020 standard, attempting to use the properties file (.json), all compiler parameters were ignored, and the task file seemed to override and ignore any efforts to get the compiler to use this flag, thus causing all attempts to use 2020 features to fail.

Does anyone have an example of task + properties file and simple main.cpp that actually works, along with specific extentions? I am using the MSFT c++ extension, and have Visual Studio Build Tools installed.

Comment: have you read https://stackoverflow.com/q/66680147/11107541 ? If you haven't, read it. if you have, why hasn't it helped you?

Comment: Read it. Honestly VSCode and C++ for me is absolutely broken. Fresh Windows 11 install. Makes no sense. I try a simple empty int main() {} with an #include <iostream> and I get:  fatal error C1034: iostream: no include path set.. I'm running around in circles with this setup I don't get it.

Comment: Don't use VSCode if you're on Windows. Use VS... It's significantly easier to use.

Comment: Funny that's exactly what I ended up doing, you are absolutely right. On the Mac it makes a lot of sense for a MSVC dev, but not on Windows. Thx.

Comment: did you open VS Code from a VS developer prompt? see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73366471/11107541